# Ionic ViewChild to Content

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to get the height of the element (or some other properties that I can eventually build up to detect when the div is in view):

In ts. for ionic project:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

...
export class itemThumb {      
    @ViewChild('mycontent') my_content: Content; 

    ...

    test() {  
       console.log(this.my_content.contentHeight);
    };

}
```

Then in html.

```
<ion-content>
      <div class="test" (click)="test();" #mycontent>Test</div>
</ion-content>
```

From the [ionic documents](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#contentHeight), it shows that I can use `@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;` to target `ion-content`.

However, instead of `<ion-content>`, I want to target my own element: `#mycontent` where I can use the `Content` instance members (such as `contentHeight`)

Of course, I can use `ElementRef` for it: `@ViewChild('mycontent') my_content: ElementRef;`

But I read that `Use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed. Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular instead. Alternatively you can take a look at Renderer2 which provides API that can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not supported.`

How would I target the div and still have access to the ionic `Content` instance members?

Any thoughts will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you intend to use the div height inside of `test()`?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. And no, it was just an example. I haven't fully figure it out, but I am trying to detect the height and total viewport height in order to detect (or trigger a function) when it is in view.